# Binding an EditorKit to a specific document model for a JTextPane

Tags: java, swing

I can't seem to figure out a way for an editor kit to work for only one JTextPane. Every time I implement one, it always functions for any JTextPane in the frame.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you set/activate the kit?

Answer (score 1):

Why not `editorPane.setEditorKit(new MyKit(())` for each of your panes?

Comment: That didn't work. I'm using StyledEditorKit to make the Actions, and they seem to work for ANY JTextPane in the frame.